# The materials tab seems to be missing

Tags: materials, import

So i imported a model from mmd, and i need to materials tab to add textures to it.
but the materials tab is nowhere to be found.
I tried selecting the model( Also tested it on a basic cube mesh, and the tab suddenly appeared )
And also tried to change the blender render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the mmd importer creates a collection and adds an instance of that collection while hiding the actual objects in the collection. (Collections don't have a material tab)

Check the Outliner and see what exactly you are selecting. You can also change the outliner display mode to `Blender File` and then search your imported model under Objects. You can then select it and should be able to change materials.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped, and it seemed to be the case with collections